# how to solve this exception in laravel ? Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I run this command to create model.

```
php artisan make:model BaseModel
```

but issue this exception

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]                   
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<<' (T_SL), expecting end of file
```

may i know how to handle this issue.

Comment: Look at your laravel.log file to have more info.

Comment: Please show your BaseModel migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your file. Check your routes, blades and controllers and search "<<". I think this is in your blade file.

```
<<input..>
<<div..> 
etc..
```